# Solid mesh with Y-shaped curves

Tags: mesh

I want to make a tree with some branches out of a curve like this simple one (I've created this with the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, convert to curve:

[image: y shaped curve]

When I set the depth to a non zero value and set the Fill settings to full, it looks like a tree with branches. But when I change the radius on the joined point, only half of the "tree" is getting bigger/smaller. When I look inside, the problem is obvious: There are essentially two separate pieces stuck together:

[image]

What can I do to get a nicely connected mesh I can work/modify on?
Is there something I do fundamentally wrong?
Is it bad practice to stuck connected parts of a mesh together?

Comment: Consider using a string of edges with the Skin modifier, instead of curves.

Comment: There is no "joined point". You have two points  of independent  curves on the same place. **A curve cannot be forked**, you cannot have a point connected to two different segments. Affecting the radius of one will not affect the other, you would need to select the other point from the other curve and modify the radius on that  one as well.